# How can I get the properties of a nested object with strange characters such as []?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to learn how to work with APIs. I am using the common openweathermap.org API. The object given by the API is:

Here is a picture of the object that is returned: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQa3Y.jpg)

Here is my js code for reference:

```
const apiUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=colombo&units=metric&appid=f41bb913b063252e007ea905d50d909f';
async function getResponse() {
    var response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    var data = response.json();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data);
}
getResponse()
```

I tried to access the properties in ways such as `data.Promise` or `data.[[PromiseResult]]` but it keeps returning errors. How can I access the properties in this object?

Comment: `var data = await response.json()`

Comment: make it the above a one-liner: `var data = await (await fetch(apiUrl)).json();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you cannot access your data at that point of the runtime is because response `response.json()` returns a Promise, not the actual data, so one option is to await as pointed out by @Keith above, or use `then()`.

If you want to dig deeper into promises, async/await, and even as historical learning, the `callback(err, res)` approach, I suggest you to check out:

- [async/await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=568g8hxJJp4)
- [promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d7s3spWAzo)